# Error while accessing class which is present in two different assemblies

Tags: c#

I have one project which has a reference of two different dlls.
When I'm creating object of that class it says below error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0433  The type 'clsRMQNew' exists in both
>   'XXXX.abc.System, Version=11.0.0.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' and 'YYYY.Common.Queue,
>   Version=16.12.26.1, Culture=neutral,

Please guide me how do i access that class from either of one assembly.
Is there any solution for the same ?

Comment: You should prefix your variable with the full qualified name of the class that you want to use

Comment: I have tried using the name name space i.e

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains with you because you have declared somewhere a variable in this way

```
clsRMQNew rmq = new clsRMQNew();
```

But it is impossible, for the compiler, to know which assembly should be used to create your variable because there are two assemblies with the same name and you haven't given any hint on which assembly to use.
Thus it stops the compilation with the error mentioned

You can fix this problem adding the whole qualified name of the class

```
XXXX.abc.System.clsRMQNew rmq = new XXXX.abc.System.clsRMQNew();
```

or

```
YYYY.Common.Queue.clsRMQNew rmq = new YYYY.Common.Queue.clsRMQNew();
```

depending on which class you want to use.

You can also shorten these declarations adding this to your using directives

```
using QueueA = YYYY.Common.Queue;
```

and then

```
QueueA.clsRMQNew rmq = new QueueA.clsRMQNew();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the class (Fully Qualify) with the specific namespace you intend to use to avoid conflicts.

```
using NameSpaceOne;
using NameSpaceTwo;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var dupObjectOne = new NameSpaceOne.DuplicateClass() { value = 1};
            var dupObjectTwo = new NameSpaceOne.DuplicateClass() { value = 2 };
        }
    }
}

namespace NameSpaceOne
{
    class DuplicateClass
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NameSpaceTwo
{
    class DuplicateClass
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir i have tried what you have suggested in the given snippet however still me getting the same error. Do i need to delete some files ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide the full name of the class:

```
var one = new XXXX.abc.System.clsRMQNew();
var two = new YYYY.Common.Queue.clsRMQNew();
```